# To findout if it's possible to align two textview specifically

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a view Like This    TextView|TextView   the problem is i want the contents inside to be vertical n equal on both sides.. Like 50/50 of the screen goes to each view(I am doing it programatically). Any suggestions... THanks

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for both textview

Comment: i am generating it programatically.

Comment: android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();      
            txtview.setWidth((int)(display.getWidth()/2))

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinearLayout` with a `android:weight` having the same value for each text views, that should do the trick. Something like:

```
textView1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5));
textView2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5));
```

(The last parameter set to 0.5 is the weight, you can set it to the value you want as long as it's the same)

Comment: Post your layout setup then, so we can see what the problem is. Because setting the weight IS the answer to what you want to do. Probably another setting in your layout prevents it from working.

Comment: android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();      
            btn.setWidth((int)(display.getWidth()/2));

Comment: This is working good.I Founf it somewhere i think it's better option if working programatically

Comment: Anyways THanx for your Efforts

Answer (score 0):

The XML version (using a TableLayout, trick works for LinearLayout also if you prefer those):

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <!-- Set the width to 0dp and set layout_weight=1! on both Views-->
        <TextView
            android:text="This is text1, its pretty long but that shouldn't be a problem"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1px"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Shorter"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And using code, this time with LinearLayout:

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
    t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    t1.setText("This is text1, its pretty long but that shouldn't be a problem");
    TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
    t2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    t2.setText("Shorter");

    layout.addView(t1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    layout.addView(t2, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```